# Why "Ich habe Hunger" and not "Ich bin Hunger"?

Tags: word-usage, noun

The sentence

> Ich bin Hunger

translates to

> I am hungry

which seems right, whereas

> Ich habe Hunger

translates to

> I have hunger

Why do Germans own or possess hunger?

Comment: Why not? All Roman languages do it as well... there is nothing weird about it

Comment: Because "Hunger" is a noun.  You'd not say "I am herpes," you'd say "I have herpes."

Comment: Why do the English have pain?

Comment: I am Hunger, the rider of Apocalypse

Comment: Why do some people think that the logic of German should be consistent with English?  Why does it make sense to say "I am hungry" after all? English is not the "truth".

Comment: @c.p. Because it's difficult for new German learners to "think in German" rather than in English.

Comment: @Dustin: I'd say it is generally a problem of people who are learning a foreign language for the first time that they expect it to be mainly a matter of learning a 1:1 mapping of vocabulary and take some time to really internalize that there are just as many differences in grammar and idioms.

Comment: Note that `I am hungry` translates to `Ich bin hungrig` (which is perfectly valid German) instead of `Ich bin Hunger`

Comment: Good I got it very nice and clear.

Comment: The translation to I am hungry is ich bin hungrig and not ich bin hunger

Comment: @c.p. I know this is old, but it's probably because both German and English are Germanic languages. Therefore it's more natural for them to be similar to each other than for German to be like Spanish or Italian. Still, exceptions exist and languages can influence each other regardless of their family of origin.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Note that the German word *Hunger* is a noun.  Just as you'd not say *I am hunger* in English, you most likely would not say *I am hunger* in German.

*Ich bin hungrig* is legal and works, but is less common than *Ich habe Hunger*.

The same goes for being thirsty:

> Ich habe Durst
>
> Ich bin durstig

Both of the above are valid but the former is far more common.

Comment: Very good exp. Is just like spanish.

Comment: "Ich hab' Hunger" is the shortest way to say that you are hungry and you don't want to waste energy on long sentences when you are already hungry. :)

Answer (score 19):

It's no different than English, really.

hungrig is an adjective meaning hungry. Hunger is a noun meaning hunger(appetite).

Thus, "Ich bin Hunger" quite literally means "I am hunger", which makes no sense in either language.

"Ich bin hungrig" means, just as in English, "I am hungry."

Additionally, you can also say "Ich habe Hunger", literally translating to "I have (got) hunger."

Admittedly, this is not good English, but one could understand it. But I can talk about how "you've got an appetite", so I don't think there's anything particularly strange about the German expression.

Answer (score 3):

Hunger can be described as a feeling - "I feel hungry" for example. You possess feelings. Therefore "I have hunger" works.

Answer (score 2):

To go into why Germans possess Hunger vs are hungry. It is a separation of self kinda thing.

I'm me. And my body is hungry. I have a body that is hungry. So via indirection I have hunger or I'm afflicted with hunger or a hungry body.

If you are or identify with your body then you are hungry. But if you identify with your spirit then you cannot be hungry but you can possess a hungry body.

Comment: "haben" in this context does not mean "to possess something" but "to feel seomething". Another example: "Ich **habe** großen Hass auf ihn - I **feel** strong hate for him". B2t: "Hunger **haben**" means "to **feel** hungry". Meaning 5 in Wiktionary entry on [haben](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/haben)