# Bedeutung von: »Er hat das Geschäft geöffnet.«

Tags: meaning, regional

In den Kommentaren zu [einer von mir verfassten Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24963/examples-when-english-is-becomes-deutsch-haben/24966#24966) hier auf german.stackexchange.com kam die Frage auf, was genau der Satz

> Herr Geiger hat sein Geschäft von 9:00 bis 19:00 Uhr geöffnet.

aussagt, bzw. wie man diesen Satz verstehen könnte.

Die von mir beabsichtigte Aussage war diese:

> Herr Geiger ist Inhaber oder Leiter eines Geschäftslokals. Kunden haben jeden Tag (mit der üblichen Ausnahme von Sonn- und Feiertagen) zwischen 9:00 und 19:00 Uhr freien Zutritt in dieses Geschäftslokal.

Der ursprüngliche Satz ist - gemäß dieser Interpretation - also als im generellen Präsens stehend zu interpretieren, weil er einen Zustand beschreibt, der, zumindest über einen längeren Zeitraum hinweg, von der Vergangenheit über die Gegenwart bis in die Zukunft immer gleich bleibt. (Vergleichbar mit »China liegt in Asien«)

Nach Meinung eines Kommentators erlaubt dieser Satz aber auch eine andere Interpretation. Wenn ich den Kommentar richtig verstanden habe, kann dieser Satz auch wie folgt verstanden werden:

> Das Geschäft wurde an einem Tag, der in der Vergangenheit lag, aufgesperrt. Dieses Ereignis fand ein einziges Mal statt.

Dabei wurde jedoch offen gelassen, ob und wie der Satzteil »*von 9:00 bis 19:00 Uhr*« in diese Interpretation passt.

Welche Argumente gibt es, die für diese Interpretation sprechen?

---

Des Weiteren wurde behauptet die folgenden Sätze wären inhaltlich gleich:

> 1. Wie lange haben Sie heute geöffnet?
> 2. Wie lange öffnen Sie heute?

Ich hingegen bin der Meinung, dass nur 1 eine angemessene Formulierung ist um zu erfragen, bis zu welcher Uhrzeit man in dem Geschäft einkaufen kann. Frage 1 bezieht sich - meiner Meinung nach -  auf die noch verbleibende Zeitspanne, in der sich das Geschäft im Zustand »geöffnet« befindet.

Die Frage 2 lässt - meiner Meinung nach - nur eine anderen Interpretation zu. Meiner Meinung nach wird mit Frage 2 gefragt, wie viel Zeit die Person mit den Schlüssel in der Hand benötigt, um den Schlüssel umzudrehen, den Rollbalken hochzuziehen, oder die Tür in eine Position zu bringen, die ein Durchschreiten erlaubt. Frage 2 bezieht sich meiner Meinung nach auf den Vorgang, bei dem das Geschäft vom Zustand »geschlossen« in den Zustand »geöffnet« übergeführt wird.

Gibt es tatsächlich Regionen im deutschen Sprachraum, in denen die Fragen 1 und 2 als äquivalent gelten? Wenn ja: Ist die von mir beschriebene Deutung der Frage 2 in diesen Regionen auch denkbar?

Comment: Für mich ist nur eine einzige Interpretation von Frage 2 möglich; sie ist aber weder identisch mit deiner Interpretation noch mit Frage 1. :-) Und zwar fragt Frage 2 für mich nach der Öffnungsdauer („drei Stunden lang“), kann aber nur sinnvoll so gestellt werden, wenn das Geschäft derzeit noch geschlossen ist.

Comment: Ah, interessant; meine Interpretation von Frage 2 scheint sich mit der von Em1 zu decken (ich hatte die Antwort noch nicht gesehen, als ich den Kommentar abgeschickt habe).

Answer (score 3):

Zu Frage 1:

Lassen wir die Uhrzeit raus und betrachten den Satz ohne Kontext, ist die Interpretation mit der Vergangenheit nicht nur offensichtlich, sondern meines Erachtens die wahrscheinlichere.

> Herr Geiger hat sein Geschäft geöffnet.

Genau genommen interpretiere ich es so, dass die Öffnung des Geschäfts erst vor kurzem war. (Hier würde man dann übrigens sogar im Englischen zum Perfekt greifen.) In aller Regel würde ich aber zum Verb *eröffnen* greifen.

> Herr Geiger hat vor kurzem sein Geschäft eröffnet/geöffnet. Ab nun können wir bequem vor Ort einkaufen gehen und müssen nicht mehr in die nächste Stadt.

Auch wenn der Zeitraum eingefügt wird, ist diese Interpretation immer noch möglich.

> Herr Geiger hat [gestern] (im Zeitraum) von 9 - 19 Uhr geöffnet. Ab nun können wir dorthin gehen.

Ohne den weiteren Kontext ist das Zeitadverb notwendig, um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden. Außerdem würde ich persönlich in diesem Beispiel noch *im Zeitraum* deswegen einfügen, weil dieser Satz Betonung auf die überraschend lange Zeitspanne legt. Aber das ist nur eine Randnotiz.

Die normale Interpretation, ohne Kontext und ohne Zeitadverb, aber mit Zeitspanne, wäre genau so, wie in deiner Antwort gemeint war.

> Herr Geiger hat von 9 - 19 Uhr geöffnet. Es sind 18 Uhr, also haben wir noch eine Stunde Zeit.

Zu Frage 2:

Auch hier gibt es tatsächlich zwei mögliche Interpretationen für Satz 2. Auch hier gilt: Ohne Kontext ist eine näherliegend und erst durch den Kontext wird die andere wirklich ersichtlich.

> Heute morgen fuhr ich am Geschäft von Herr Geiger vorbei, als er gerade sein Geschäft aufschloss. Leider hatte ich nicht viel Zeit und wusste, dass ich auch erst spät wieder zurück komme. Also fragte ich ihn nur eben: "Wie lange öffnen sie heute?"

Die Interpretation, wie lange der Öffnungsprozess dauern mag, fände ich hier absurd. Das, was mir sofort in den Sinn springt, ist die Frage nach der Dauer der Öffnungszeit.
Auch wenn Satz 1 mit Sicherheit eleganter ist, so ist Satz 2 nicht falsch und in meinen Ohren auch nicht ungewöhnlich. Ob das regional-bedingt ist, weiß ich nicht.

Es sei noch angemerkt, dass ich das Beispiel bewusst so gewählt habe, weil der Satz mir nur dann natürlich vorkommt, wenn die Frage vor dem Öffnen gestellt wird.

Comment: Interessante Interpretation von »Wie lange öffnen sie heute?«. Diese Möglichkeit wäre mir nie in den Sinn gekommen, aber die Erläuterung ist nachvollziehbar. Dies würde ich zwar eher so formulieren: »Wie lange haben Sie heute offen?«, aber darum ging es zugegebenermaßen auch gar nicht.

Comment: Ist der Öffnungsprozess des Ladens abgeschlossen wenn die Tür auf ist, oder ist der Öffnungsprozess abgeschlossen, wenn die Tür wieder zu ist?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Der Öffnungsprozess ist abgeschlossen, sobald die Tür offen ist. Wenn sie wieder zu ist, ist auch der Schließungsprozess abgeschlossen. – Dauert natürlich in der Realität beides nur wenige Minuten, weswegen das Beispiel eigentlich hinkt.

Answer (score 3):

**Zu Frage 1:**

Welche Argumente gibt es? Nun, eine streng semantische Analyse des Satzes lässt diesen Schluss zu. Wir wissen nicht, ob es ein Präsens mit Adjektiv ist oder ein Perfekt. Nimmt man aber die Pragmatik dazu, die unter anderem davon ausgeht, dass beide Dialogpartner ein Interesse an einem erfolgreichen Dialog haben, so ist die Perfekt-Variante extrem unwahrscheinlich, es sei denn der Kontext passt. Wäre das tatsächlich meine Message, würde ich es anders formulieren. 
Insofern haben wir es hier meiner Ansicht nach mit einem gewollten Missverstehen zu tun. Das kann man mit sehr vielen Sätzen machen, wenn man Langeweile hat (mit diesem zum Beispiel auch).

**Zu Frage 2:**

Lustigerweise ist das für mich genauso ein Fall. Die reine Semantik lässt theoretisch zu, dass es um die Dauer des Aufsperraktes geht. Man kann das so verstehen, wenn man wirklich will, genauso, wie man im Mond einen Hasen sehen kann (ich sehe da ein Gesicht). Das ist regionsunabhängig.
Die Pragmatik allerdings spricht dagegen. Keiner, der sich normal verständigen will, würde den Sachverhalt, dass der Öffneprozess so und so lange dauert, in dieser Weise ausdrücken. 
Jetzt mag man hören „Aber ich verstehe es nun mal so.“
Da würde ich dann mal Folgendes anmerken wollen:

- Satz 1 ist rein semantisch einfach nur das Perfekt von Satz 2.

Wenn man Satz 2 im Sinne der Aufsperrdauer versteht, dann sollte man Satz 1 ganz genau so interpretieren. 
Alles andere ist ein bisschen unglaubwürdig.

1. Ich lese eine Stunde ein Buch.
2. Ich habe eine Stunde ein Buch gelesen.
3. Ich öffne eine Stunde den Laden .
4. Ich habe eine Stunde den Laden geöffnet.

Es fällt mir wirklich extrem schwer zu glauben, dass in Österreichisch ein solcher Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen der Präsens- und der Perfektversion besteht. Das wäre in der Tat faszinierend.

**Fazit:**

Mit so Erbsenzählerei sollte man immer vorsichtig sein. Die fallen einem schnell mal durch die Finger auf den Boden der Tatsachen und dann kann man die alle wegschmeißen.

Comment: Ich lese da zwischen den Zeilen heraus, dass du den Verdacht hast, ich würde die Frage 2 (»Wie lange öffnen Sie heute?«) durchaus auf Anhieb im gleichen Sinn wie Frage 1 verstehen, die beschriebene Variante für eventuell möglich halten, und hier nur so tun, als gäbe es für mich nur die Variante mit der Öffnungsdauer. Jedenfalls verstehe ich deinen unschönen Hinweis auf die *Erbsenzählerei* so. Ich kann dir aber versichern, dass ich unter »etwas öffnen« tatsächlich etwas ganz anderes verstehe, als »etwas ist/hat offen/geöffnet«.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast.. ja so ist es gemeint. Ich glaube gern, dass die andere Bedeutung für dich präsenter ist, als für mich. Wenn aber ein Typ zu dir sagt: "Ich öffne meinen Laden heute 2 Stunden", glaube ich kaum, dass du da irgendwelche Zweifel hast, was er meint. Und wenn, dann müsstest du sie bei der anderen Version auch haben. Und ja, "etwas öffnen" ist ein anderes Verb als "etwas ist/hat geöffnet" aber darum ging es hier nicht. Es geht um "ich öffne etwas" vs. "ich habe etwas geöffnet"

Answer (score 3):

*Haben* kann auch dazu verwendet, dem Subjekt Eigenschaften zuzuschreiben:

> Sie hat eine Krankheit.
>   Sie hat die Haare schön.

In Kombination mit Partizip II hat *haben* drei Funktionen:

- Ich habe den ganzen Tag gearbeitet. (Perfekt)
- Der Hund bekommt die Pfote verbunden → Der Hund hat die Pfote verbunden. (Eigenschaft und Resultativ des Rezipientenpassivs.)
- Er hat den Laden jeden Tag von 09:00 bis 18:00 geöffnet. (Eigenschaft)

Da das Perfekt deutlich häufiger ist, kann man auf die anderen Formen nur durch „Weltwissen“ schließen. Ein Hund verbindet sich die Pfote nicht selbst und beim Laden ist es ein stehender Begriff. Oft gelingt der Schluss auch durch den Kontext:

> Chef zum Angestellten: „Ich will das Problem bis heute Abend gelöst haben!“

Dies lässt sich sinnvoll umstellen in „Ich will bis heute Abend ein gelöstes Problem haben.“ Dies kann man auch an den anderen Sätzen zeigen:

- ?Ich habe den ganzen gearbeiteten Tag.
- Der Hund hat eine verbundene Pfote.
- Er hat einen von 09:00–18:00 Uhr (jeden Tag) geöffneten Laden.

Soweit ich weiß, kann man mit dem ersten Satz den Ursprung des Perfekts erklären: wer den ganzen Tag gearbeitet hat, hat einen gearbeiteten Tag. Das Perfekt betont, dass in der Vergangenheit etwas geschehen ist, dass Auswirkungen auf die Gegenwart hat.

Comment: Tipp: Wenn du am Zeilenende zwei Leerzeichen setzt, gefolgt von einem Zeilenumbruch, erscheint der Zeilenumbruch auch im gerenderten Text; du musst also nicht auf `<br />` zurückgreifen ;-) (Es will mir leider keine zwei Leerzeichen als Code angeben D=)